# multitaperTrend function in R

Tags: r, time-series, spectral-analysis

How would you determine the "B" in `multitaperTrend` function?
I have been trying to estimate trend for Southern Oscillation index data using `multitaperTrend` function. But I do not know how to determine the argument B (Bandwidth) in the function. I tried to use
equation NW=BT, but without any success.

Comment: In which R package is that function? Please augment your post with that information!

Comment: That function, multitaperTrend, exists in the multitaper R package.